# How can I make a variable in a dataset containing a vector of all numbers between two other variables?

Tags: r

Here's an example dataframe.

```
x <- c(1,2,3)
y <- c(10,10,10)

d <- data.frame(x, y)
```

I want to generate a third variable (z) containing a vector of all values in x:y. For example, the first value of z should be c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10).

How can I do this? Trying `d$z <- d$x:d$y` just gives the error "numerical expression has 3 elements: only the first used."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 mapply(":", x, y)
```

Same as RLave answer but without requiring extra packages.

Answer (score 1):

With `purrr` package and the function `map2`:

```
purrr::map2(x,y, function(x,y) x:y)

# [[1]]
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
# 
# [[2]]
# [1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
# 
# [[3]]
# [1]  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Of course this needs to give a `list` because of the different lengths. Note that the same could be achieved with a simple loop.

Answer (score 1):

Also base R:

```
d$z <- lapply(1:nrow(d), function(i) with(d[i, ], x:y))

> str(d)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ x: num  1 2 3
 $ y: num  10 10 10
 $ z:List of 3
  ..$ : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
  ..$ : int  2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
  ..$ : int  3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```